# how to publish a web service in juddiv3 using eclipse

Tags: eclipse, web-services, tomcat, uddi, juddi

I am new to Web Services. I was trying to publish a JAX-WS Web Service to apache juddiv3 using eclipse(indigo) Web Service Explorer. But each time I try to publish it following error is produced:

```
IWAB0135E An unexpected error has occurred.
UDDIException
Message part {urn:uddi-org:api_v2}get_authToken was not recognized.  (Does it exist in   service WSDL?)
```

I am using following components:

(i) Eclipse Indigo (EE version).

(ii) juddi-portal-bundle-3.1.2

(iii) Windows 7

While publishing the web service I am using following entries under the 'actions' section of the eclipse 'Web Service Explorer':

1. Publish=Business
2. Publication Format=Simple
3. Publish URL= "http://localhost:8080/juddiv3/services/publish"
4. UserID = root
5. Password = Root
6. Name = Business1

Many times when I press 'Go' button then 'Please wait. The operation is still in progress'  message is also displayed even after a long time.

Kindly help me with this issue.

Kindly suggest if there is any other framework other than juddiv3 which could be used to create private UDDIs on local machines.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Its a known issue the eclipse plugin. A bug has been filed.

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=307202

FYI, the jUDDI team is working on adding v2 endpoints to the v3 server. This use case is one of the drivers. It's almost in a working state now and will be released with the 3.2 version of jUDDI.